# Node-Red Raspi GPIO: Using only rising trigger

Tags: gpio, nodered

When using node-red with raspberry pi 3 GPIO, node-red will send a message, every time the state changes (= rising and falling trigger). Is it possible to only send messages on rising trigger?

Using a script afterwards is not the solution.

Comment: This sounds like something that the documentation of node-red should answer.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: no.

Workaround: feed output from your GPIO input node into a switch node with only 1 rule:

```
msg.payload > previous value
```